# Pthread program runs slower as thread increases

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I'm a beginner in parallel programming and I tried to write a parallel program with pthread library. I ran the program on a 8 processor computer. The problem is that when I increase `NumProcs`, each thread slows down though their tasks are always the same. Can someone help me to figure out what is happening?
`

```
#define MAX_NUMP 16
using namespace std;
int NumProcs;

pthread_mutex_t   SyncLock; /* mutex */
pthread_cond_t    SyncCV; /* condition variable */
int               SyncCount; /* number of processors at the barrier so far */

pthread_mutex_t   ThreadLock; /* mutex */

// used only in solaris. use clock_gettime in linux
//hrtime_t          StartTime;
//hrtime_t          EndTime;  

struct timespec StartTime;
struct timespec EndTime;

void Barrier()
{
  int ret;

  pthread_mutex_lock(&SyncLock); /* Get the thread lock */
  SyncCount++;
  if(SyncCount == NumProcs) {
    ret = pthread_cond_broadcast(&SyncCV);
    assert(ret == 0);
  } else {
    ret = pthread_cond_wait(&SyncCV, &SyncLock); 
    assert(ret == 0);
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&SyncLock);
}


/* The function which is called once the thread is allocated */
void* ThreadLoop(void* tmp)
{
  /* each thread has a private version of local variables */
  long threadId = (long) tmp; 
  int ret;
  int startTime, endTime;
  int count=0;
  /* ********************** Thread Synchronization*********************** */
  Barrier();

  /* ********************** Execute Job ********************************* */
  startTime = clock();
  for(int i=0;i<65536;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<1024;j++)
        count++;
  endTime = clock();
  printf("threadid:%ld, time:%d\n",threadId,endTime-startTime);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  pthread_t*     threads;
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  int            ret;
  int            dx;

  if(argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: %s <numProcesors>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(-1);
  }
  assert(argc == 2);
  NumProcs = atoi(argv[1]);
  assert(NumProcs > 0 && NumProcs <= MAX_NUMP);

  /* Initialize array of thread structures */
  threads = (pthread_t *) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * NumProcs);
  assert(threads != NULL);

  /* Initialize thread attribute */
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setscope(&attr, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM); // sys manages contention

  /* Initialize mutexs */
  ret = pthread_mutex_init(&SyncLock, NULL);
  assert(ret == 0);
  ret = pthread_mutex_init(&ThreadLock, NULL);
  assert(ret == 0);

  /* Init condition variable */
  ret = pthread_cond_init(&SyncCV, NULL);
  assert(ret == 0);
  SyncCount = 0;

  Count = 0;

  /* get high resolution timer, timer is expressed in nanoseconds, relative
   * to some arbitrary time.. so to get delta time must call gethrtime at
   * the end of operation and subtract the two times.
   */
  //StartTime = gethrtime();
  ret = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &StartTime);

  for(dx=0; dx < NumProcs; dx++) {
    /* ************************************************************
     * pthread_create takes 4 parameters
     *  p1: threads(output)
     *  p2: thread attribute
     *  p3: start routine, where new thread begins
     *  p4: arguments to the thread
     * ************************************************************ */
    ret = pthread_create(&threads[dx], &attr, ThreadLoop, (void*) dx);
    assert(ret == 0);

  }

  /* Wait for each of the threads to terminate */
  for(dx=0; dx < NumProcs; dx++) {
    ret = pthread_join(threads[dx], NULL);
    assert(ret == 0);
  }

  //EndTime = gethrtime();
  ret = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &EndTime);

  printf("Time = %ld nanoseconds\n", EndTime.tv_nsec - StartTime.tv_nsec);

  pthread_mutex_destroy(&ThreadLock);

  pthread_mutex_destroy(&SyncLock);
  pthread_cond_destroy(&SyncCV);
  pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you increase the number of threads past the number of physical cores on the system, there will be a performance penalty. I assume that since you're ``MAX_NUMP == 16``, that you're on an 8-core Xeon with HyperThreading. While you'll get better scaling with HT past 8 threads than you would without it, the scaling is not linear and is workload dependent. Therefore the individual time-per-thread to complete a task may increase slightly, but the overall throughput (number of task per time) increases at a faster rate.

Comment: This is, of course, assuming you don't have any resource contention/deadlock problems with you mutexes.

Comment: Could you provide some benchmark data? I'm unsure what is the reason of the slowdown only from the code.

Comment: Intel has a [pretty good white-paper about it](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-insights-to-intel-hyper-threading-technology). In general HT gives you maximum scaling when the workload has many reads from system memory or L3 cache, and worst scaling when the workload can fit completely in L1. Since your toy benchmark code is much closer to the latter, you're going to get worse scaling than you'd see with real workloads.

Comment: [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)?

Comment: The situation is that when I double the NumProcs, the run-time of each thread doubles, which really makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your observation is expected.

The main factors that usually impact this situation (worker spinning on local computation) are:

- The ratio nb_threads / nb_available_machine_cores
- The affinity of each thread

The optimal scenario here is when you have a ratio of 1, and each thread has a unique affinity with one of the core.

The idea is to maximize each core throughput. You can do that by having one and only one thread running on each core. If you increase the number of threads (ratio > 1), several threads will share the same core, forcing the kernel (through the task scheduler) to switch between the execution of each of them. This is what you were observing.

Each time the kernel has to operate such a switch, you pay for a context switch. It may become a noticeable overhead.

Note:

You can use [pthread_setaffinity](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html) to set the affinity of your threads.

Comment: I tried to use pthread_setaffinity_np() in each Threadloop(), but the result is still the same. The run time of each thread doubles when I doubles the NumProcs. How could I tell they are running on different cores?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this in release mode (O3 compiler flag) then there are two things wrong with ThreadLoop():

1) There is never any external usage of the 'count' result, so the compiler will omit computing it because it has no visible effect.

2) Even if there had been external usage of 'count' then the compiler will compute the result at compile time and simply emit the value directly.

You can see all this if you disassemble the binary.

You can declare 'volatile int count' to bypass both problems or you can compile with O1 compiler flag or do both.

The loop should scale pretty linearly with number of threads because there is no memory contention. By the way, you should increase the loop iterations because I think the duration could be close to the noise ratio...